# Algolia bug with Infinite Search

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

Currently using the infinite search method that Algolia supplies through their instantSearch.js.

The following scenario is happening:

1. Search for an item
2. Refine the list
3. Load more pages up to page 5
4. Scroll back to the top and change refinement
5. Nothing happens

By the looks of it - it's appending the results of the new refinement to the results that are already there. I'm looking to make it resent the results, not sure if this is a bug with instant search itself?

```
   search.addWidget(
      instantsearch.widgets.numericRefinementList({
        container: '#price',
        attributeName: 'salePrice',
        options: [
          {name: 'All'},
          {end: 20, name: 'less than 20'},
          {end: 50, name: 'less than 50'},
          {start: 50, end: 100, name: 'between 50 and 100'},
          {start: 100, end: 300, name: 'Expensive'},
          {start: 300, name: 'Very Expensive'}
        ],
        templates: {
          header: 'Price'
        }
      })
    );
```

And the infinite search code:

```
search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.infiniteHits({
    container: '#infinite-hits-container',
    templates: {
      empty: 'No results',
      item: hitTemplate
    },
    hitsPerPage: 3
  })
);
```

Comment: I have reproduced your issue in jsFiddle using another index: https://jsfiddle.net/bobylito/cbj43209/

Comment: The bug is being tracked here: https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch.js/issues/2195

Comment: Thanks Boby. I've commented on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues is fixed in 1.11.15 (instructions for getting the new version [is here](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#setup))